# How to Vectorize Computation

Tags: r

I am trying to Vectorize a for loop to execute quickly.

```
n = 1000000
x= numeric(n)
for (i in 1:n) x[i] = rpois(1,3) + rpois(1,5)
```

Comment: Just `x <-  rpois(n,3) + rpois(n,5)`. No need for a loop.

Comment: Yeah, you just need two lines: `n <- 100000   ;   x <- rpois(n, 3) + rpois(n, 5)`